# Symfony 2.5 - [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\OCI8Exception]

Tags: oracle, symfony

I have this error message:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\OCI8Exception]
```

This is the content of `/app/logs/dev.log` after executing `php app/console cache:clear` and `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`:

```
[2018-04-11 08:01:51] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
[2018-04-11 08:01:52] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2018-04-11 08:01:52] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate". [] []
[2018-04-11 08:02:05] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
[2018-04-11 08:02:05] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2018-04-11 08:02:05] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate". [] []
```

Whenever I try to use this command:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

All I want is to update my entities in Oracle database.

This is my `parameters.yml`:

```
parameters:
database_driver: oci8
database_host: *********************
database_port: 1526
database_name: tgp
database_user: appsread
database_password: ******** // 
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: localhost
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
locale: en
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
debug_toolbar: true
debug_redirects: false
use_assetic_controller: true
```

Also it doesn't create any entity in the database whenever we generate entity. Sorry I'm only new to Symfony. I tried searching but still can't find an answer.

**UPDATE:**

After executing `php -m`:

```
[PHP Modules]
bz2
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gmp
hash
iconv
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mysql
mysqlnd
oci8
pcre
PDO
PDO_ODBC
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

Comment: Please paste exception's message

Comment: Please provide the complete error message. You can also check the logs in var/log/prod.log or dev.log. Are you on Linux? If yes, what does php -m show?

Comment: I now have added the list of modules and the error logs on my question

Comment: Is there really no message given in the exception?

Comment: @malarzm & @Nico Haase, unfortunately there's no other message included only this `doctrine:schema:update [--complete] [--dump-sql] [--force] [--em[="..."]]`. That's why we only rely on the error log.